# How to use icons in jQuery Mobile Framework (without using a button)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am looking to use the delete icon that is built-in to jQuery Mobile.

I know how to use buttons, you just use `data-role` - but I want to use it inside a plain old `span` or `div`.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried to just change-out an `<a />` tag for a `<span />` tag? http://jsfiddle.net/rUPxQ/1/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just use a `div` with the classes specified, for example

```
<div class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete"></div>
```

Update:

The style-sheets for JQM have changed since this was first posted, you can get the same affect by adding the `ui-btn-icon-notext` class to your element (at least as of JQM 1.4.5). Additionally you might need to add a `position:relative;` to get it positioned correctly.

For example

```
  <span class="ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-delete" style="position:relative" />
```

[Here's a link to the relevant API](http://api.jquerymobile.com/icons/)

Comment: @Haseeb I posted this for an earlier version of JQM, I updated my answer with an example for the current version.

Comment: style='position:relative' is important as Roman answered below

Comment: @ehrhardt perhaps, but at the time I guess it wasn't necessary. I answered this question in 2012.

Comment: @ehrhardt At any rate, I've updated my answer to include that information. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 14):

Just upgraded to JQuery Mobile 1.4.0 -- Uh!... Nothing worked, until the following work-around:

```
<span class="ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-left " style="position:relative;" />
```

Note the class `ui-btn-icon-left` (you could use other ones `-right`, `-top`, `-bottom`, `-notext`, but this one seems to work the best).  Most importantly, the `style="position:relative"` finally placed it within my container.

Happy coding...

Comment: Thanks!  I'm also using 1.4.0 and was have trouble figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow" style="display:block" />` or simply referenceing the `ui-icon-delete` class in your markup?

Comment: thanks but this doesnt seem to do anything. I know in regular jquery you can do that, but it doesnt work on mobile

Answer (score 0):

add data-iconpos="notext"

Icon positioning:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.2/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html